# Ajax,Jquery passing data from database to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make pivot table 'save_events' and controller 'color'. In controller a make query and I sending it to Ajax. Then I get events_id (its a column in my pivot table) and I use console.log(JSONObject.eventColored[0].events_id); to check id events and its work fine. But I need pass it to other function which must change background-color events. And I don't know how I should do this.

```js
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar') }}/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var base_url = '{{ url('/') }}'; 
$.ajax(
  {    
        type: "GET",
        url: "{!!route('color')!!}",             
        dataType: "json",
        data:{"events_id": '' },                 
        success: function(data)
        {
          var JSONString=data;
                //var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                //console.log(data);      
                console.log(data.eventColored[0].events_id);
              var color_events=data.eventColored[0].events_id;

                  $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
  weekends: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek'
  },
   eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
      $('#modalBody').html(event.name);
      $('#eventUrl').attr('href','/home/zapis/'+event.id);
      $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm '));
      if (event.end) $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm '));
      else $("#endTime").html('');         
      $('#fullCalModal').modal();
      return false;
    },

  eventLimit: true,
  FirstDay: 1,
        contentheight : 650,
        editable : true,
        allDay : false,
        aspectRatio : 2,
        slotLabelFormat : 'HH:mm:ss',
        timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
        displayEventEnd : true,
        events: {
    url: base_url + '/api',
    error: function() {
      alert("cannot load json");
    }
  },
   eventColor: 'white',

  eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view, color_events) {
  if(event.id==color_events){
    element.css('background-color', '#cccccc');           
  }
    else
    {
      if (event.title == "Wydzial 1") 
      {
          element.css('background-color', '#378006');
          }
          else if(event.title == "Wydzial 2")
          {
          element.css('background-color', '#ff0000'); 
          }
          else if(event.title == "Wydzial 3")
          {
          element.css('background-color', '#73e600'); 
          }
          else{
          element.css('background-color', '#0066ff');
          }
        }
  }

});

  }

});

});

</script>
```

**At the point my problem: in Ajax I got JSONObject.eventColored[0].events_id and I cant use it in eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view)** 
I got this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: JSONObject is not defined .eventAfterRender@http://localhost:8000/home:206:1
```

And Controller(project what I make is using Laravel 5.4):

```html
class Color extends Controller
{
    public function colorEvent()
    {
        $eventColored =  DB::table('save_events')->get(['users_id','events_id']);

        return response()->json(['eventColored'=>$eventColored])->$eventColored = array('eventColored' => $eventColored );

    }
}
```

**Loop:**

```js
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
  var color_events = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.eventColored.length; i++) {     
    color_events.push(data.eventColored[i].events_id);  
  };


  console.log(color_events);
  console.log(event.id);
if(color_events==event.id){

        element.css('background-color', '#cccccc');

}

  else
  {
    if (event.title == "Wydzial 1") 
    {
        element.css('background-color', '#378006');
        }
        else if(event.title == "Wydzial 2")
        {
        element.css('background-color', '#ff0000'); 
        }
        else if(event.title == "Wydzial 3")
        {
        element.css('background-color', '#73e600'); 
        }
        else{
        element.css('background-color', '#0066ff');
        }

      }
}
```

Console

```
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
1  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
5  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
6  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
7  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
8  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
9  home:243:5
Array [ 8, 9, 7 ]  home:242:5
10
```

ok i trying explain it. Fullcalendar get 1 table named "Events" there is all of the event who user can look at homepage. Next think what user can do is click to event and join to it then its make new record in pivot table "save_events" << there is 2 column users_id and events_id and this pivot table is made on relationship between table "Users" and "Events". And events on fullcalendar got diffrent colors depending about tittle e.g. if tittle got name "Wydzial 1" color is red else title will be "wydzial 2 " color blue else title will be "wydzial 3 " color green else title will be "wydzial 4 " color yellow. And if User join to event i want do somethink like that e.g events with tittle "wydzial 1" got red color and when user click on it and join to this event it will be change color for grey. I write post up link to github there is my project. So at finish calendar showing all events what moderator(one of users role) create, and user can join(accept,save) event, if someone join to event it will automatically change back-ground color for a grey.

Comment: I do somethink like that: var color_events = $.ajax and next i pass it to if(event.id==color_events) but its not work events dont change background-color

Comment: `var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`. This line is completely pointless. The output (JSONObject) is identical to the input (data).

Comment: "I cant use it in eventAfterRender". No, because it isn't defined at that time. It does not get populated until after the ajax call has finished. Ajax calls run _asynchronously_, so your fullCalendar code, including the eventAfterRender event, will run _before_ your "success" callback in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: You have 2 options, I think: 1. Whatever code runs in the "color" controller, run it also in the code which creates the fullCalendar events in the first place - then you can find the event and change its background property _before_ you ever send it to the browser. This then removes the need for an additional ajax call to the server immediately after you load the page.

Comment: 2. Move the code which creates the fullCalendar into the "success" callback of your ajax call. Then you can guarantee that the event ID will be available when the "eventAfterRender" code runs.

Comment: But if i delete var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); and i make console.log(eventColored[0].events_id); i got error

Comment: and what error is that? I can't read your screen, or your mind! I imagine the command ought to be `console.log(data.eventColored[0].events_id);` though.

Comment: ReferenceError: eventColored is not defined

Comment: Since `eventColored` was a property of the `JSONObject` variable in your existing code, it's trivial to see that it must have come from the `data` object originally. It doesn't exist as a separate variable (look at your code - where did you define it??), hence why you get a "not defined" error. As I already said, the command should be `console.log(data.eventColored[0].events_id);` - now that we have removed the pointless `JSONObject`, we just refer to `data` directly.

Comment: i edit my post with changes and u fix error thx but still event.id == color_events its not work

Comment: maybe will helpfull event.id is from event in fullcalendar events_id is from pivot table save_events. event.tittle is working but event.id what is really important isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
 eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view, color_events) {
```

Have a look at the definition of eventAfterRender. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/. There is no such parameter variable as `color_events` in the callback. You can't just invent your own callback parameters - nothing will be populated into them, because fullCalendar doesn't know about them.

You declare `var color_events` higher up in the code, which is right, but then your declaration of another `color_events` in the callback parameters of the eventAfterRender function means that a new, separate `color_events` variable is declared within the scope of the function, and the `color_events` you declare earlier with a wider scope is temporarily ignored.

To fix it, just remove the fictitious `color_events` parameter from the callback signature:

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
```

Now, the version of `color_events` declared earlier will be in scope and have the correct value.

If you're not sure why this works, please read a tutorial about JavaScript variable scoping.

With regard to your loop:

1) The first mistake is that `data` is not an array, it's an object. So you there's no point doing `.each()` on it, because you know the object's property names and you already know you're interested in the `event_colored` property. `event_colored` *is* an array though - hence why you can already do `event_colored[0]` to get the first element of it. So it's event_colored that you want to be the subject of your loop - your inner loop already does this, using conventional JS syntax rather than jQuery, but it makes no difference.

2) Every time you run `color_event = [(data.eventColored[i].events_id)];` it just overwrites the `color_event` variable with a new array containing the latest event ID. The correct way to add items to an array is using the `.push()` method. A quick google search on JS arrays would tell you this.

I assume you then want to compare all the IDs from `eventColored` with the event IDs in fullCalendar? If so, the quickest way to do this is as follows. You've already got an array (`data.event_colored`) which is in scope of the `eventAfterRender` method, so just use it directly there, rather than trying to create a second array:

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.eventColored.length; i++) {
    if (event.id == data.eventColored[i].events_id) {
     element.css('background-color', '#cccccc');        
    }
    else
    {
      //..etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i do something and its work now i must figure how in ajax get all rows from table becouse i get only one. I first time working in ajax i dont event expect i will use it in my project.

Comment: And its true this not working i just spending for this a lot of hours and i trying everthink i copy pass and thats why  my code is ugly now:p

Comment: lol well I hope you learned something useful, the best way to learn is by trying! :-)

Comment: i spending on this small think 3 days 7-8h every day

Comment: ok wow. Did you do any tutorial on ajax first before you started? It might help with some of the basics, like understanding the asynchronous execution, variable context etc.

Comment: no ;p and i know its a big misstake i spend a lot time to reading doc and video tutorials and like u probably see my eng its not a perfect;p

Comment: I got one question about looping in ajax var color_event = "";
    $.each(data, function (color_event) {
        color_event += data.eventColored[0].events_id;
    }); i trying do that and i dont know how i should make it correct in php its for me easier

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve with that loop? What is your desired output? I can't tell you what is "correct" unless you tell me what you want from it.

Comment: var color_event =data.eventColored[0].events_id;  i get only one row from table so i need use loop to get all rows from column events_id

Comment: i've edited my answer to include some more info. Please consider an extra upvote if it helps :-)

Comment: i trying do like u write but its not work but when i add data.eventColored[i].events_id its change color but only 1 event change its not working on the rest events i edit loop maybe i make some misstake but i am not sure

Comment: maybe show your data. How many events are you expecting it to change? do those IDs definitely exist in the current fullCalendar view?

Comment: i edit loop now i get somethink like that i push data.eventColored[i].events_id to var color_event and dont work so i was thinking object cant be working with array so i change event.id to array but still doesnt work;/

Comment: elements in data can all the time change becouse its depending about user adding event to full calendar

Comment: thats same with pivot table rows its depending how many user save on event

Comment: ok I understand it can change over time, but you said "only 1 event change its not working on the rest events" so I assumed you had some specific test data where you were expecting it to change more than 1 event. If so, post that data so I know what you want to achieve. And make sure the loop is exactly as I've shown you. Don't go changing it without showing _exactly_ what you've changed - I can't help you when I don't know your code or data.

Comment: your loop (in the edited question) is not like my example. In yours you make an entirely new array (which is not necessary) and then try to compare _the entire array_ to one single event ID. This will never work. You have to loop through the array and compare _each single element_ against event.id. And you don't need a second array to do it. If you copied my example properly it should work.